# 3D plot of two 2D functions

Tags: plotting, functions

I would like to plot two 2d functions in a 3d coordinate system. Examples are `z = x^2` and `z = y^2`. Each function has one independent variable, (either `x` or `y`),  and a global dependent variable (`z`).

Comment: You've seen `Plot3D[]` already?

Comment: yes, of course, but i would like to show two independent 2d functions, eg. z=x^2 and z=y^2 in a xyz coordinate system.

Comment: Then what's wrong with `Plot3D[x^2+y^2,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]` ?

Comment: Well, `Plot3D[{x^2, y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` works for me...

Comment: The Plot3D Argument merge these functions into one surface object, i would like to show them independent in, zy and zx layer.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot3D` with the curves parametrized as `{t,0,t^2}, {0,u,u^2}`.

Comment: What do you mean by zy layer? Why do you refer to a sum in the text of the question?

Answer (score 6):

For the two curves use the command:

```
g1 = ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 0, t^2}, {0, u, u^2}}, {t, -10,10}, {u, -10, 10},
     BoundaryStyle -> Thick];
```

in addition, if you want also to have the two $x-y$ and $y-z$ planes in the plot:

```
planes = ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z,0, 100}, 
         Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.4]], 
         Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}];

Show[g1,planes,PlotRange->{All,All,{-10,10}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: many, many thanks. that's what i am looking for!

Comment: @pauleck, if this answers your question you should click on the check mark and the up-arrow next to the answer (to up-vote it - as I just did...) If you still want to wait for other answers, it's OK to leave the check mark unchecked until a day or so later.

Comment: @Jens, OP has rep $1$; unless he is [given rep](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (say, by upvoting his question), he won't be able to upvote Spawn's answer. He can certainly accept Spawn's answer, if it suits his needs.