# Combining 2D slices into a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I am currently trying to combine several 2D plots into one big 3D plot. The 2D-plots are simply input-results from calculations (so these things have 2D coördinates (x,y)). The results depend on an integer parameter n, and what I now want to do is combine these results on one big plot (with n on the z-axis).

I tried to do this with graphics3D, but the problem is that i the need the command Texture[] which rasterizes the background and thus yields difficulties when combining the plots. Is there a way to get the background out?

An example of my problem is given (when you look for example at the function y^2==a*x, where you want to vary the parameter a):

`Show[Table[
  Graphics3D[{Texture[
     ContourPlot[y^2 == a*x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, 
      ContourStyle -> Hue[(a - 1)/4], Background -> None]], 
    Polygon[{{-\[Pi]/2, -\[Pi]/2, a}, {\[Pi]/2, -\[Pi]/2, 
       a}, {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, a}, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, a}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"], {a, 1, 5, 0.5}]]`

which yields 
[image]

What I want to have is something like:

[image]

I don't know if there are any ways to get the background of Texture[] away ?

> The actual question:
>
> **Given a set of 2D plots (which depend on some paramter "a"), how can I stack these 2D plots in a 3D plot (where the additional axis contains my parameter "a") without losing the background transparency of the different independent plots ?**
>
> *Context of the question:*
>
> For example if you want to calculate a phase diagram of a physical system, then you will compare the free energy F(p,V,T) of the different phases for different values of T. Depending on which one is the smallest you can assign a color to the 2D plane, leading to a 2D "plot" of colors with coördinates. If I want to know how my different phases behave (in the (p,V)-plane) as a function of T, then I need to stack my different 2D planes.

Comment: related ( with images.. ) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35581/transparency-in-image-used-for-texture

Comment: Some related questions: [159](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159/using-listpointplot3d-to-simulate-2d-plots-moving-in-time), [1413](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions), [23665](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23665/3d-plot-of-two-2d-functions)

Comment: do you specifically need to use `Texture` for some reason ?

Comment: @george2079, no, not at all! I'm just new to this and Texture[] seemed like the way to go. I just want to know if there is a way to stack 2D plots into a 3D plot without losing the transparancy of my white background.

Comment: A general remark: I'm not looking to stack contourplots, there are indeed easier ways to do this. I'm looking on how to stack individual (more or less independent) 2D plots.

Comment: @Nick I've made some changes according to your phase diagram context.

Comment: @Nick See e.g. [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5670#5670)  maybe also żMap a 3D plot into planeś(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/map-a-3d-plot-into-plane/9366#9366)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
ContourPlot3D[y^2 == a*x,
   {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {a, 0.9, 5.1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {Table[a, {a, 1, 5, 0.5}]}, 
   ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, opts___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[p, 
   g /. Line[v_] :> {Hue[((p ~Part~ v[[1]] ~Part~ 3) - 1)/4], Thick, Line[v]}, opts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Response to updated question**

It's not clear that the above method cannot be adapted to the "context of the question", as described.  But let's address the problem of assembling a more-or-less random list of plots that "depend on an integer parameter n."

```
Show[MapIndexed[# /. {Graphics[g_, opts___] :> 
      Graphics3D[g /. p : {_Real, _Real} :> Join[p, #2], 
       FilterRules[{opts}, Graphics3D]]} &,
  plots
  ],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True]
```

Note: it will fail if the graphics contain `Text`/`Inset` objects using the offset and direction parameters.  They ought to remain 2D coordinates.  Unless, that's a problem for the OP's use-case, I intend to leave that restriction in place.  A similar restriction also exists for graphics that contain transformations.

**P.S.** Hint as to how to use `Texture` is in my comment below.  But you have to generate the plots correctly first, so I feel it is disqualified, if we are to treat the plots as given.

Comment: that is exactly how I generated the second plot. Don't focus on the y^2=a*x to much since it was just an example to generate a figure with. My real question is: "Given a set of 2D-plots (with not necessarilly a functional prescription), how can I stack these 2D plots in order to get a 3D image ?"

Comment: @Nick, then here's another way that works for your example but won't work for you: `Show[Table[Graphics3D[{Texture[Image@ContourPlot[y^2 == a*x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, ContourStyle -> Hue[(a - 1)/4, 1, 1, 1], ContourShading -> Opacity[0]]], EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{-π/2, -π/2, a}, {π/2, -π/2, a}, {π/2, π/2, a}, {-π/2, π/2, a}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"], {a, 1, 5, 0.5}]]` :)  Well, it's a bit slow anyway.

Comment: Depending on whether any exact numbers or constants were present, using  `_?NumericQ` might be robust.

Answer (score 12):

A method of assembling 2d contour plots ...

```
 Show[Table[
     Graphics3D@
         First@Cases[
            Normal@ContourPlot[y^2 == a*x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
                  Frame -> False], 
                      Line[x_] :> {Hue[(a - 1)/4], Line[Append[#, a] & /@ x]}, 
                      Infinity], {a, 1, 5, .5}] ,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, george, it's a bit funny that you correctly surmised the OP's intention from the the first, but (so far) have accumulated the fewest upvotes.  Ah, the whimsical nature of SE!  Anyway, +1 for dead heat (so far).

Comment: @george2079, that's already a nice way to go! How would I need to do this if I were given a set of 2D plots, where each 2D slice depends on a parameter a ? I want the a-axis to be the extra z-axis in which I stack my 2D results. 

My question comes from the fact that for future calculations my 2D plots will be generated by a general calculation (minimalization proces) and that the results will be stacked as for the example.

Answer (score 8):

A quick one based on your phase diagram context, where `bg` contains the color of your 2D planes:

```
g = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{y^2/a, y, a}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> Hue[(a*2 - 1)/10]], {a, 1, 5, 1}];

bg = Table[ContourPlot3D[z == a, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, .8, 5.2}, 
Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Hue[1 - (a*2 - 1)/10], Opacity[0.3]]], 
{a, 1, 5, 1}];

Show[g, bg, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-2, 2}, {0.4, 5.2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's indeed similar to how I generated the second picture. The is not what I'm looking for exactly ...

Comment: @Nick I made some changes according to your phase diagram context. Is this what you want?

Comment: the answer is really nice, but the problem is that you already start from a parametric 3D plot. What I am asking is: "Given a set of 2D plots", where each 2D slice is determined by a paramter a, how do I combine them into a 3D plot with an additional axis a.

The example that I have given was with the function y^2=a*x, but for practical purposes I'd need a general method since my future 2D plots will just be a collection of x and y values.

Comment: @Nick If you only care about the final output, you could, in theory, put the data of your 2D slices in a list and replace `g=Table[...]` with `g=ListPlot3D[...]` in my answer. It's not exactly stacking 2D plots but the end result may look the same. For example, one way to get the data from `Plot[...]` is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the setting for the option `Mesh` to include graphics directives:

```
ContourPlot3D[y^2 == a*x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {a, 0.9, 5.1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {Table[{a, Hue[(a - 1)/4]}, {a, 1, 5, 0.5}]}, 
 ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SliceContourPlot3D`:**

```
cols = Reverse@(Hue[Rescale[1 - #/5, {0, 1}]] & /@ Range[1, 5, 1/2])

plot = SliceContourPlot3D[y^2 - x #
      , {"ZStackedPlanes", {#}}
      , {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 1, 5}
      , Contours -> 1
      , ContourShading -> Opacity[0.2, Hue[Rescale[1 - #/5, {0, 1}]]]
      , BoundaryStyle -> Hue[Rescale[1 - #/5, {0, 1}]]
      , ContourStyle -> {Directive[Thick, 
         Hue[Rescale[1 - #/5, {0, 1}]]]}
      , SphericalRegion -> True
      ] & /@ Range[1, 5, 1/2] //
   Show[#
     , AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "a"}
     , AxesEdge -> {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1, -1}}
     ] &;
Legended[plot,
 Placed[SwatchLegend[cols, Reverse@Range[1, 5, 1/2]
   , LegendLabel -> Style["a", Bold, 12]
   , LegendLayout -> "Column"
   , LegendFunction -> "Frame"
   ], After]
 ]
```

[image]