# Combine Multiple ListDensityPlots into 3D Cube

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions on how best to go about creating an image of several ListDensityPlots merged into a single 3D cube (with only the axes, not the full frame). For example, I have the following 4 ListDensityPlots:

```
data1 = Table[Sin[j^3 + 2 i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data2 = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data3 = Table[2 Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data4 = Table[( Cos[i j] - 3 j), {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
p1 = ListDensityPlot[data1, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
p2 = ListDensityPlot[data2, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
p3 = ListDensityPlot[data3, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
p4 = ListDensityPlot[data4, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

What I am trying to do is visualize them as vertical slices in a cube. Unfortunately, the data I am actually using are not from the same distribution, but rather represent flow from distinct rivers over date (z-axis) and time (x-axis). From what I understand, I don't think [ListSliceContourPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceContourPlot3D.html) will work here, or is there a trick I could use to make it work that I'm just not seeing?

Honestly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Could you include your actual dataset, or at least a portion of it? It still seems to me that one should be able to tweak `ListSliceDensityPlot` to work for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` would work. Modify your data as follows:

```
data1 = Table[{i, 0, j, Sin[j^3 + 2 i]}, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data2 = Table[{i, 2, j, Sin[j^2 + i]}, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data3 = Table[{x, 4, y, 2 Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
data4 = Table[{i, 6, j, (Cos[i j] - 3 j)}, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
```

This assumes you want vertical slices in `x` and `z` at each of the `y`-values `0`, `2`, `4`, and `6`. You can then combine your data into one list as

```
data = Flatten[Join[data1, data2, data3, data4], 1];
```

Finally,

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"YStackedPlanes", {0, 2, 4, 6}]
```

I'm not sure that you can specify different color schemes for different slices, but the result of the above is

[image]

It doesn't look great! And I think that's because each slice is on the same scale, and so if one of your sets of data has a larger width, then the other slices aren't going to show as many features.

You might want to look at

- [Combining 2D slices into a 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77039/combining-2d-slices-into-a-3d-plot)
- [Plotting several functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, thanks to the advice above, I've found the trick.

```
data1 = Evaluate[
    Table[Sin[j^3 + 2 i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/20}]] // N;
data2 = Evaluate[
    Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/20}]] // N;
data3 = Evaluate[
    Table[2 Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi/20}]] // N;
data4 = Evaluate[
    Table[( Cos[i j] - 3 j), {i, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/20}]] // N;
(* Transpose the data *)
data = Transpose[{data4, data3, data2, data1}];

(* Create separate ListSliceDensityPlot3D graphics for each style *)
ls1 = ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"YStackedPlanes", {2, 3, 4}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", Boxed -> False];
ls2 = ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"YStackedPlanes", {1}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Boxed -> False];

(* Combine in show as one *)
Show[ls1, ls2]
```

[image]