# Create a 3D stack of 2D line plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics3d, data, image3d

A simple concept but I've not been able to solve it. I'm trying to create a stack of 2D plots in 3D space using Mathematica 9. **This is not a parametric plot**, but I'm creating it from an array of vectors (imported 
 .csv file). The ListPlot3D function creates a filled mesh but what I want is this type of plot (created by HYRY in StackExchange: *'Matplotlib plot pulse propagation in 3d'*):

[image: example taken from StackExchange question: 'Matplotlib plot pulse propagation in 3d']

I have tried changing the function options for ListPlot3D and was going to create an array of plot images (.jpg) to stack in 3D, each one having an alpha value - but that would not be good. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Marc

Comment: see: [77039](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77039/5478) and topics linked in comments there.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way, using `Graphics3D` and starting from a list of $x,y,z$ values for datapoints.

Mock data:

```
data = Flatten[Table[
  {x, y, PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{0.2, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.4}}],{x, y}]}, 
  {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.25}],1];
```

Group by y-value:

```
gb = GatherBy[data, #[[2]] &];
```

Some fancy styling (not necessary):

```
cLines = Transpose[{
  ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length[gb]]],
  Line /@ gb
}];
```

And plot (with some options to help the plot styling):

```
Graphics3D[
 {Thick, cLines},
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this is great! I did not think about reformatting the data first.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html):

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2 - y^2/(4 + x^2/4) + x y];
ParametricPlot3D[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {y, -5, 5}], {x, -5, 5}, 
                 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]  ]

Comment: Thanks Yohbs - I'm trying to do this for an array of vectors (e.g. imported .csv) rather than for a list a parametric values.

Comment: No problem. In retrospect I still think the easiest solution is simply using `ListPlot3D` with the `Mesh` option as detailed in the question @Kuba referred to.