# Contourplot with three variables

Tags: plotting

I have the following equation to generate a contour plot for it:

```
ContourPlot[{(6 x^2 (-0.00001 + (z)^2))/(6 y^2) == 0.2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 20}]
```

It has three variables. The range of the two variables is given above but the variable `z` has range of `{10, 100}`. My question is how to introduce the `z` range here while I want the usual contour plot in two dimensions.

Comment: Similar to [77039](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77039/combining-2d-slices-into-a-3d-plot).

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Either, plot a family of curves,

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[
   (6 x^2 (-0.00001 + (z)^2))/(6 y^2) == 0.2,
   {z, 10, 100, 15}],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 20},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y}),
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[10, 100, 15],
   LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14]]]
```

[image]

Or [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) the `z` value

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  (6 x^2 (-0.00001 + (z)^2))/(6 y^2) == 0.2,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 20},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y})],
 {{z, 10}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {z}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Look at a `ContourPlot3D` from above:

```
ContourPlot3D[(6 x^2 (-0.00001 + (z)^2))/(6 y^2) == 0.2, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 20}, {z, 10, 100},
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5,
  ContourStyle -> None, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Further, I want the y-axis to be a log scale. I tried the "Scaling function", but it does not work. Any suggestion this, please?